White splash screen appears when going back to previous page in .NET MAUI when using Prism navigation
I am developing a .NET MAUI application and using Prism navigation instead of using Shell navigation for page navigation. I am using Prism.DryIoc.Maui library version 9.0.401-pre. But when using GoBackAsync() to back to the previous page, it goes back to the page, but before going to the previous page, a white splash screen is appearing for a fraction of seconds. But this is happening just on Android device, and not on iOS. Can anybody hep me to sort this issue out.
Please provide me a full example where Prism navigation is using for .NET MAUI application.
